# How do I run a python script on boot on Google Coral?

Tags: python-3.x, google-coral

I have written a simple test code in python to toggle two of the I/O pins on and off every few seconds. I would like to be able to run this code whenever the board powers on so that I don't need to bring a keyboard, mouse, and monitor everywhere I want to run the simple test. How do I do this on Mendel OS on a google coral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mendel OS, your systemd service should look like this:

myservice.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example systemd service.
After=weston.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
PAMName=login
Type=simple
User=mendel
WorkingDirectory=/home/mendel
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/test_service.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Regarding how to create a service and how to deploy it, you can follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units) article.

Change 'ExecStart' line with your python file that you want to get executed.

Answer (score 2):

Using crontab has been working consistently for me, you may want to add a time.sleep in the beginning of your python file

edit crontab 
`crontab -e`

select nano editor

add

`@reboot sudo python3 <path_to_your_script>`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.
This might be useful for you. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd
I was able to add new service into systemd, but the script didn't run properly, but perhaps this won't be your problem.

Comment: Please try to give at least the basics of the contents of the answer here, and not only as a reference to an external site, even if it is from the Stack Overflow network.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the instruction from [the Nam Vu's note in Gist](https://gist.github.com/Namburger/1f42de2bd9a316e6e8f6538ec599c676). This is like the details of [Nanoj's answer above](https://gist.github.com/Namburger/1f42de2bd9a316e6e8f6538ec599c676).

---

This is an example of starting a systemd object detection service on boot on the Coral Dev Board.

1. create a file called "detects.service" with similar with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=systemd object detection service
After=weston.target

[Service]
PAMName=login
Type=simple
User=mendel
WorkingDirectory=/home/mendel
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/detect_service.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Copy the file to "/lib/systemd/system/detects.service"
   `$ sudo cp -i detects.service /lib/systemd/system`
3. Create a file called "detect_service.sh" with similar to following content:
   `edgetpu_detect --model fullpath/mobilenet_ssd_v2_coco_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite --label fullpath/coco_labels.txt`
   or
   `python detect.py --model fullpath/mobilenet_ssd_v2_coco_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite --label fullpath/coco_labels.txt`
4. Make it executable and copy it to "/usr/bin":
   `$ sudo chmod u+x detect_service.sh`
   `$ sudo cp -i detect_service.sh /usr/bin`
5. enable the service with the systemctl command:
   `$ sudo systemctl enable detects.service`

This would be useful when your python code called [the Google "gstreamer code"](https://github.com/google-coral/examples-camera/blob/master/gstreamer/detect.py#L34) example. The gstreamer code not able to be executed with sudo command, so you may not able to use with "sudo crontab -e" method for example [Danny Dasilva's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123872/5595995).